# How to import a function and a custom type into DataStage?

Tags: import, oracle11g, datastage, custom-data-type

I've been provided an Oracle package as origin for an ETL process. The package contains one function that takes a date as parameter and returns a collection of a custom type.

My question is, how can I import this into a DataStage job? Importing the table definition with the Stpred Procedure connector cannot import the specific data, and looks like there's no way to import a custom type into DataStage. Google, surprisingly, has no answers.

Thanks in advance,

Léster

Comment: Have you tried writing the answer to a string or a file and then parsing it?